# How can I select a certain data point in my CSV file and graph all the values that are + or - 1 from the value?

Tags: python, pandas, graph

The code to find the Values is Below

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
import math as ma

df = pd.read_csv("/Users/aaronhuang/Desktop/ffp/exfileCLEAN.csv")
df_top = df.head()
num = pd.read_csv('/Users/aaronhuang/Desktop/ffp/exfileCLEAN.csv', usecols=[1])

stand = round(num.std(), 4)
conf = float(stand * 3)
avgs = round(float(num.mean()), 4)


i = 0
while(i < len(df['Magnitude '])):
    if(abs(df['Magnitude '][i] - avgs) >=  conf):
        print(df['Time '][i])

    i += 1
```

The output is this:

```
[6102 rows x 3 columns]
2455338.895
2455350.644
2455391.557
2455404.776
2455413.734
2455451.661
2455473.49
2455477.5209999997
2455507.505
2455702.662
2455734.597
2455765.765
2455776.575
2455826.5930000003
2455842.512
2455866.508
2455996.796
2456017.767
2456047.694
2456058.732
2456062.722
2456071.924
2456082.8019999997
2456116.494
2456116.535
2456116.576
2456116.624
2456116.673
2456116.714
2456116.799
2456123.527
2456164.5069999998
2456166.634
2456391.703
2456455.535
2456455.6
2456501.7630000003
2456511.616
2456519.731
2456525.49
2456547.588
2456570.526
2456595.515
2456776.661
2456853.543
2456920.511
2456953.496
2457234.643
2457250.68
2457252.672
2457278.526
2457451.89
2457485.722
2457497.93
2457500.674
2457566.874
2457567.877
2457644.495
2457661.5530000003
2457675.5130000003
```

I am trying to take the values above, from the time column (shown below) and + and - 1 from the values and graph them.

Here is a part of the data:

```
            Time   Magnitude   Magnitude error 
0             NaN         NaN               NaN
1     2455260.853      19.472             0.150
2     2455260.900      19.445             0.126
3     2455261.792      19.484             0.168
4     2455262.830      19.157             0.261
...           ...         ...               ...
6097  2457686.478      19.063             0.176
6098  2457689.480      19.178             0.128
6099  2457690.475      19.386             0.171
6100  2457690.480      19.092             0.112
6101  2457691.476      19.191             0.122
```

For example, if one of the values is 2455260 (no2) I would want it to graph the Time values (2455260.853, 2455260.900, 2455261.792) against their Magnitude Values (19.472, 19.445, 19.484)

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to plot values within plus or minus 1, rows before and after (row number + or - 1)?

Comment: Also please show what you have tried

Comment: Hey Tom, I would like to ploot the values within plus or minus one. I am unsure of how I should start and was hoping for a few pointers. Thanks